# Differential amplifier, calculation of differential and common gain

Tags: amplifier, differential, gain, calculation

Maybe someone can help and knows how to calculate the differential gain and common-mode gain in a differential amplifier.
Will the formula for differential gain be Ad=Rc/2Re, i.e. in my case 50/40=1.25? I don't know how to calculate the total.

Can this be measured in Multisim?

Diagram with parameters in the photo.

[image: First diagram]

[image: Second diagram in which a current source was used]

Comment: Are you asking for theory and how to calculate things? If so, just simplified theory using a simple linearization around an operating point? Or large scale theory that illustrates the arctan behavior more fully? Or are you asking for a complete schematic testbed that you can use for simulation purposes in order to extract numerical values?

Comment: I would like to know what formulas to use and which values to substitute (values from the attached diagrams) to calculate it correctly.

Comment: Please consider reading [this](https://pages.hmc.edu/mspencer/e151/sp21/notes/20.pdf).

Comment: V3 should be -15V

Comment: Ok, You right V3 is now reversed. But my osciloscope show:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAPWZ.png) Is this correct?, or shouldn't it show a second wave. Am I missing something in the multisim?

Comment: @grigoriii - Hi, FYI an OP (original poster) *must not* ask questions as an "answer" here on SE. It breaks the whole Q&A approach and causes future problems when these non-answers get deleted. (An OP should only post an answer when it is the full & final end to a question.) To add images in a comment, use [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310525) technique. Note that the draft answer (or question) *must not be submitted*. It is used only to upload the image & is then discarded. I moved your "non-answer" into a comment ^^ If you need more help with this, please ask on our [meta]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- The so-called "**differential gain** Vd" is based on the assumption that Vin1=-Vin2. Therefore, the current increase in Q1 is identical to the current decrease in Q2. As a result, the current through the common emitter node remains constant and we can treat this node as signal ground. That means: The gain Vd (referenced to one collector output) is identical to the gain of a simple common-emitter gain stage without feedback:

  **Vd=(+ -)gm*Rc** (gm: transconductance; gm=Ic/Vt).
- In case of **common-mode operation** in both transistors the current increase (resp. decrease) is identical. So this current increase causes a feedback voltage across the resistance in the common emitter leg (static Re, or dynamic re when there is a 3rd transistor). Without additional calculations, we can use the known gain expression for a common-emitter stage with feedback. However, because the current  increase/decrease is twice that of a single transistor, the feedback resistor must be doubled in the gain formula:

  **Vcm=-gm*Rc/(1+2gmRe)**

  (in case of a 3rd transistor replace Re by re (large dynamic transistor ouput resistance)

Comment: OK, but i have problem with second circuit (second image), with additional power source. What values to substitute into the formula to calculate it?

Comment: As I have mentioned in my answer:  Replace Re by a "dynamic re when there is a 3rd transistor". This is the large output resistance (often called "ro") of the 3rd transistor.